# How to plot a specific color value in gray scale in edge of the image

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, colors

I have the below image and want to plot a specific single value on the defined line.  In the case below I used the red color for the mentioned line just to visualize the line.

The values are normalized by subtracting them from the mean and divided by standard deviation. Therefore, values are not between 0 and 1, and also RGB.  The value could be 0.1, 2, or any other value. I want to just write that specific value on the line and then save it as a mat file.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pixels = 600
my_dpi = 100

one_coord = [[-150,-200],[300,-200],[300,0],[150,200],[-150,200]]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=( pixels/my_dpi,  pixels/my_dpi),facecolor='k', dpi=my_dpi)  
plt.axes([0,0,1,1])
rectangle = plt.Rectangle((-300, -300), 600, 600, fc='k')
plt.gca().add_patch(rectangle)
plt.plot([one_coord[0][0], one_coord[-1][0]], [one_coord[0][1], one_coord[-1][1]], color='r', lw=5)
plt.axis('off')
plt.axis([-300,300,-300,300])
plt.imshow(fig)
```

Comment: You can just use `color='0.3'` (a number between quotes, and between 0 and 1 is interpreted as a grey value) [specifying colors in matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colors.html)

Comment: The values are not between 0 and 1.

Comment: I want to save image as a mat file and use it as input to my cnn network.

Comment: If you have  rgb values between 0 and 255, you can also use `plt.plot(...., color=(r/255, g/255, b/255))`.  When saving the image, `color='0.3'` will be rgb (77,77,77) or grey value 77 (or something else, depending on the format).

Comment: Are you asking how to *convert* a range of floats into a grayscale value? ... normalize it? `value / (max-min)`??

Comment: [matplotlib.colors](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib-colors)

Comment: [matplotlib.colors.Normalize](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Normalize.html#matplotlib-colors-normalize)

Comment: I normalized the values by subtracting them from the mean and divided by standard deviation. Therefore, there are different values without any certain range. The value could be 0.1, 2, or any other value. I want to just write that specific value on the edge and then save it as a mat file.